# Ultra electrostatic capacitor generator

Tags: capacitor, electrostatic

[image]

Part B of ultra capacitor 1 and 2 are connected to ultra capacitor 3 to provide potential difference.

Part B includes charge collector and electrode.

Part A of ultra capacitors 1 and 2 include the rest of components of ultra capacitor.

When part A and B are connected the positive charges will be repelled from ultra capacitor 2 through load to capacitor 1 and negative charges will be attracted from 1 to 2.

When A and B are separated potential difference will be removed from parts A of capacitor 1 and 2 so parts A will both neutralize. This happens in intervals of 0.5 seconds.

Do you think energy 3125J of capacitors 1 and 2 (1000F) will flow per second through load every time part B is connected to part A. or current of 2500columbs/second will flow.
Will power per hour through load be
2500 x 2.5v x 3600seconds = 22,500,000 watt-hours

the reason to use three capacitors is that capacitors 1 and 2 will block the discharge of capacitor 3 but use its potential difference when parts A and B are connected.

capacitors 1 and 2 are unrolled so that parts can be separated to neutralize charge.

Comment: What is the point of having 3 capacitors? Wouldn't a single capacitor do the same job? Why do they have to be 'ultra' capacitors? You have drawn a battery across capacitor 3. Is this an actual battery (and if so, what voltage)? _"2500 x 2.5v x 3600seconds = 22,500,000 watts"_ - no, it isn't. Do you mean Watt seconds?

Comment: 2500 J= 2500 W-s    ( not  J * s)

Comment: I've never heard of unrolling capacitors. Is this a new audiophile tweak?

Comment: First learn the difference between energy, power, charge and current, then fix the errors in the question so it makes sense.

Comment: @successahead:  You can't build what you are dreaming of.  You want to build an electrostatic generator based on the capacitance of very large value capacitors.  Your diagrams fail to convey the fact that some of the plates of your capacitors are moving.  The distance between the plates is an important part of the capacitance. When you separate the plates to make them move, you have increase the gap between  them - drastically reducing the capacitance.

Comment: [Read up on the construction of supercapacitors.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor)  Your generator plan implies spinning an enormous area (tens to hundreds of square meters) of extremely flimsy materials (a small fraction of a millimeter thick) at high speeds (50Hz amounts to 3000 RPM.)  Do you see any potential problems with that plan?

Comment: @JRE this is not about spinning, creating a gap between electrodes or 0.5 seconds, then contact them again.

Comment: Then there's no need to unroll the capacitors, is there?

Comment: show voltage before and after on each cap value and action taken. Use a logic symbol diagram with real values

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 i cant do that that why i ask the experts

Answer (score 0):

The smaller Caps will discharge faster in series (dV/dt=I/C) and the cap on the right might become reverse charged **if you think a Cap only has one electrode.**
The stripe indicates Negative.

Boom.

Comment: i tried it with film capacitors. when film capacitors 1 and 2 are separated that's dielectric and plate as part A they neutralize and when placed back they charge again. but their current is low so it needs doing the process very fast which is difficult. the caps are not polarized. i wanted to reverse charge to neutralize the capacitor when plates are separated